# Html file cannot find Servlet with link given

Tags: html, servlets, hyperlink

I can't get my index.html file to call my getEmployees.java  servlet and I don't know why it's not working because im using the servlets url pattern.
The getEmployees method is then supposed to forward control to the listEmployees.jsp file.

The error occurs when I click the hyperlink in the html page;

HTTP Status 404 - /getEmployees

type Status report

message /getEmployees

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.3

And the code;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>


        <a  href="/getEmployees"> View Employees </a>


    </body>
</html>
```

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/getEmployees"}) 

public class getEmployees extends HttpServlet {

      /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {


           Employee E1 = new Employee("Rick Astley", 1234);
           Address A1 = new Address("63 Elm Street");
          Position P1   = new Position("Gentleman",20000);
           E1.setAddress(A1);
           E1.setPosition(P1);

             Employee E2 = new Employee("Jesus", 5555);
           Address A2 = new Address("desert");
          Position P2   = new Position("Full-time son of God",0);
           E1.setAddress(A2);
           E1.setPosition(P2);


            List<Employee> storage = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            storage.add(E1);
            storage.add(E2);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
             session.setAttribute("List", storage);

             RequestDispatcher dis=request.getRequestDispatcher("listEmployees.jsp");  
                dis.forward(request,response);


            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet listEmployees</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet listEmployees at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason deleting the servlet and renaming it to NewServlet and rewriting the code fixed this. I have no idea why.